# SCHED_RR policy to control scheduling (POSIX or Linux)

Tags: linux, multithreading, posix

My ultimate goal is to do some testing on multithreading programs on POSIX systems (*not only* Linux); and I hope to diversify the interleavings by intervening the schedules.

---

UPDATE: an example to explain my goal

For example, suppose the program will eventually run two threads, T1, T2.
At the function level (or other levels such as instruction level, basic block level), suppose they have the following traces:

T1: A1 -> B1 -> C1
T2: A2 -> B2 -> C2

During the actual execution on one machine, there might be only a few interleavings. e.g., in an extreme case, no matter how many times the program execute, there is only one interleaving A1 -> B1 -> A2 -> B2 -> C2 -> C1 on one machine; but may be it's possible another interleaving A1 -> A2 -> B1 -> B2 -> C2 -> C1 happens on another machine, while this interleaving introduces a bug. Therefore I hope to *diversify* the interleaving by adding some scheduling controlling POSIX function calls (we have an automatic way to adjust the scheduling policy and priority dynamically), so that after running several versions of these schedule-adjusted programs it will *at least provide more interleavings* (but I don't care about the *exact* interleaving). For example, with one adjustment, it may execute trace A1 -> A2 -> B1 -> B2 -> C2 -> C1 with a higher chance; with another adjustment, it may execute trace A1 -> B1 -> A2 -> B2 -> C2 -> C1 or A1 -> B1 -> C1 -> A2 -> B2 -> C2 or other traces with a higher chance. In this sense, we increase the testing coverage.

---

Presently I'm thinking about instrumenting some code to adjust with different scheduling policies and priorities. And I came across `SCHED_OTHER` and `SCHED_RR`.

By default programs run with `SCHED_OTHER`. However it seems that POSIX standard hasn't detailed the requirements (see [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_08.html) although I'm not sure whether this is the latest standard). Specially, it even does not say whether it is round-robin. And by reading [Linux sched man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html) and [Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/2/html/Realtime_Reference_Guide/chap-Priorities_and_policies.html), it says the static priority is fixed 0 and the *dynamic priority* is

> **based on** the nice value and is **increased** for each time quantum the thread is ready to run, but denied to run by the scheduler

To me, this seems to say **setting *nice value* still cannot control the priority like what `SCHED_RR` does**.
This other major issue is that setting nice value **per thread** may not be possible for other POSIX systems other than Linux

> According to POSIX.1, the nice value is a **per-process** attribute; that
>          is, the threads in a process should share a nice value.  However, on
>          Linux, the nice value is a per-thread attribute: different threads in
>          the same process may have different nice values.

Therefore, I'm thinking whether it's possible to use `SCHED_RR` (`SCHED_FIFO` is out of my considerations since it is not time quantum based thus will greatly change the schedule) to simulate `SCHED_OTHER`'s behavior, since most of the programs I would like to instrument use the default `SCHED_OTHER` policy. I have come up with some naive ideas:

1. Since unprivileged `SCHED_OTHER` programs have nice value between 0 and 19, I can ensure the priority for the `SCHED_RR` instrumented programs to be within this range; if this still has changed the behaviors greatly, I can narrow down this range more, e.g., 0~5.
2. I will make sure *all* the threads I would like to investigate to have the same `SCHED_RR`.
3. I can make the `time slice/quantum` to be equal or similar to the value that is used by `SCHED_OTHER` (e.g., on Linux, by changing values inside `/proc/sys/kernel/sched_rr_timeslice_ms`, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401294/how-to-know-linux-scheduler-time-slice)) (again, I don't know to *set* the time quantum for `SCHED_OTHER`).

So may I know:

1. Is this idea reasonable for POSIX?
2. Or if this is not general to POSIX, may I know whether it's correct for Linux only?
3. Or if using `SCHED_RR` still changes behaviors greatly from the default `SCHED_OTHER` on Linux, what are possible ways to do more interventions on multithreading scheduling on Linux?

Other relevant links:

- [How to increase thread priority in pthreads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649281/how-to-increase-thread-priority-in-pthreads)
- [Linux SCHED_OTHER, SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_RR - differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392415/linux-sched-other-sched-fifo-and-sched-rr-differences)
- [Scheduling Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324593/scheduling-policy)
- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_for_real_time/7/html/reference_guide/sect-using_library_calls_to_set_priority
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_rr_get_interval.2.html
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setschedprio.3.html
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setschedparam.3.html
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chrt.1.html

Comment: At least in Linux? FIFO and RR are realtime, RR is pure preemptive round robin with fixed priority and    a more priority task is always scheduled before any less prioritive task. OTHER is the traditional multi-level-feedback RR, means that task that have not been scheduled for a time have an increasing priority, this is a pure overall timesharing system. Now I am not sure to understand what you want to do, at least it seems very difficult to achieve (trying to enforce various interleaving).

Comment: Yes, at least for Linux. What I'm going to do is to intervene the scheduling for the threads so that I can *test* the multithreading program more effectively. Will update the question a bit.

Comment: updated with an example to explain my purpose.

Comment: Testing multithreaded programs is a real challenge. You may either run multiple times under different conditions (that's hat's is usually done), add some small random-timed code everywhere to slow down a little bit your critical code (that is also very often done), or you may try to change the scheduling (there exists a way to do it in realtime under linux, can't remember exactly something like Coccinnelle from Gilles Muller ?)

Comment: Thank you Jean! will follow your advice and do some searching